# Parse JSON in python to a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

A bit lost after much research. My code below parses the JSON to a dictionary I have thought using json load

```
response = json.load(MSW) # -->Will take a JSON String & Turn it into a python dict
```

Using the iteration below I return a series like this which is fine

```
{u'swell': {u'components': {u'primary': {u'direction': 222.5}}}}
{u'swell': {u'components': {u'primary': {u'direction': 221.94}}}}

ourResult = response
for rs in ourResult:
    print rs
```

But how oh how do I access the 222.5 value. The above appears to just be one long string eg response[1] and not a dictionary structure at all.

In short all I need is the numerical value (which I assume is a part of that sting) so I can test conditions in the rest of my code. Is is a dictionary? With thanks as new and lost

Comment: This question does not appear to be about parsing JSON, but about navigating nested Python dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use python syntax as follows:

```
>>> print response['swell']['components']['primary']['direction']
222.5
```

Comment: Many thanks. Seems so obvious now. Appreciate the support. I hope to be able to answer some questions here i  future.

Comment: @user3787389, You certainly can. I joined the site to ask a few questions and before I knew it, I was answering as well. It is actually a really good way to learn. Especially all the top quality answers from all the others on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Just access the nested dictionaries, unwrapping each layer with an additional key:

```
for rs in ourResult:
    print rs['components']['primary']['direction']
```